# If index-match object doesn't exist, want to return something other than #N/A

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have an Excel file with 2 sheets. Sheet 1 has a list of item #s and corresponding risk-levels. Sheet 2 also has a list of Item #s, and it uses index-match to extract the risk-level from sheet 1. I've created an example to illustrate:

Sheet1:
[image: sheet 1]

sheet 2:
[image: sheet 2]
.

On sheet 2, I highlighted 2 items that don't exist on sheet 1 in pink; because of this, they return #N/A. Instead, I want them, and any other items that don't exist on Sheet 1, to say "Needs to be added." How do I change my index-match formula to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could wrap it in an `IFERROR` statement: `IFERROR(<your current formula>,"Needs to be added.")`

Comment: I'm new to this community, can someone explain to me why this answer was given in a comment instead of an answer? Thanks in advance